# Gnuplot gamma function

Tags: python, gnuplot

How can you plot a gamma CDF reaching a value of 1 for a gamma function with k > 2 in GnuPlot? When k >= 2, gamma(k) < 1, and because igamma(k, x / theta) is in [0, 1] (in gnuplot), your CDF formula limit is gamma(k). It gives me a plot like this[image: gamma CDF]

The code used is the following one:

```
set grid
set yrange[0:*]

gamma1_pdf(x, k, theta) = (1 / (gamma(k)*theta**k))*x**(k-1)*exp(-(x / theta))
gamma1_cdf(x, k, theta) = (1 / gamma(k))*igamma(k, (x / theta))

set term windows 0
plot gamma1_cdf(x, 1.0, 2.0) lc rgb "red", \
     gamma1_cdf(x, 2.0, 2.0) lc rgb "orange", \
     gamma1_cdf(x, 3.0, 2.0) lc rgb "yellow", \
     gamma1_cdf(x, 7.5, 1.0) lc rgb "black"

set term windows 1
plot gamma1_pdf(x, 1.0, 2.0) lc rgb "red", \
     gamma1_pdf(x, 2.0, 2.0) lc rgb "orange", \
     gamma1_pdf(x, 3.0, 2.0) lc rgb "yellow", \
     gamma1_pdf(x, 7.5, 1.0) lc rgb "black"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `help igamma` gnuplot implements the *normalized* incomplete gamma function which approaches 1 for large x, whereas the [unnormalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Asymptotic_behavior) version approaches the values of the Gamma function in that limit.

Fortunately it is easy to undo the normalization:

```
set xrange [0:30]
igamma2(a,x) = igamma(a,x)*gamma(a)    # unnormalized incoplete gamma function
gamma1_cdf(x, k, theta) = (1 / gamma(k))*igamma2(k, (x / theta))

plot gamma1_cdf(x, 1.0, 2.0) lc rgb "red", \
     gamma1_cdf(x, 2.0, 2.0) lc rgb "orange", \
     gamma1_cdf(x, 3.0, 2.0) lc rgb "yellow", \
     gamma1_cdf(x, 7.5, 1.0) lc rgb "black"
```

[image]